# Conditionally redirecting directory structure URL to html file

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My goal is to redirect any url such as `http://mydomain.com/somename` to `http://mydomain.com/somename.html` except for `http://mydomain.com/name1` and `http://mydomain.com/name2`  For these two, I wish to redirect them to `http://mydomain.com/main.php?g1=name1` (or name2, etc).  If these later two have two or three more directories in the URL (i.e. `http://mydomain.com/name1/val2/val3`), I wish to add them as individual GET values such as `http://mydomain.com/main.php?g1=name1&g2=val2&g3=val3`.  I would like the browser to keep showing the directory path, and not something like `http://mydomain.com/somename.html`.

Below is my unsuccessful attempt. How can I accomplish this?  Thank you

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

## If the request is for a valid directory, file, or link, don't do anything
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/name1 [OR] RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/name2
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ ?p=$1&c=$2&v=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ p=$1&c=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ ?p=$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea in most places, but you need to change the order of your rules to match more specific stuff before less specific stuff.  Generally, I'm allowing a trailing `/` in the rules below via `/?`. Remove that from the end if you won't permit a trailing `/` to be matched.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# This should be fine as you have it....
## If the request is for a valid directory, file, or link, don't do anything
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Reverse your rule order here.
# First match name1|name2 with an optional trailing /
# but nothing else following...
RewriteRule ^(name1|name2)/?$ main.php?g1=$1 [L,QSA]
# Two additional dirs
RewriteRule ^(name1|name2)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ main.php?g1=$1&g2=$2&g3=$3 [L,QSA]
# Three additional dirs
RewriteRule ^(name1|name2)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ main.php?g1=$1&g2=$2&g3=$3&g4=$4 [L,QSA]

# Last, do the generic rule to rewrite to .html
# using [^.]+ to match anything not including a .
# You could be more specific with something like [a-z]+ if that
# corresponds to your expected input
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]
```

If you wanted to check that the URI is not `name1, name2` in a condition, use an `[AND]` which is implicit:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/name1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/name2
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I think you meant `$4` at the end there.

Comment: Michael, You are awesome!  I have been going crazy on this.  Just curious, but could a condition be created which states that it is not name1 or name2, and then perform the html rewrite?

Comment: @user1032531 Yes, but it isn't an `OR`, it is an `AND`. If it is not name1 AND it is not name2, do the following... I find it easier to work from specific to non-specific though, and avoid `RewriteCond` as much as possible, relying instead on `RewriteRule`.